# Cloud storage on kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

unresolved reference storage

I try to connect on cloud storage with this method

```
var storageRef= storage.reference
```

But storage stay red and I can’t import

Comment: The message that I’ve got “ unresolved reference storage”  My gradle :

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the implementations and follow the detailed [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start#kotlin+ktx)

> ```
>  dependencies{
>   implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.3.0')
>   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
>  }
> ```

2. Sync project and check once

Comment: See the message I’ve got when I use the implementation : if I run my app I have this message : caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.defaultlenientconfiguration$artifactresolveexception: could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugruntimeclasspath'.